# Remove Sentinel 2 tiles with a given cloudy pixel - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, point-of-interest

I have a point of a given latitude and longitude.

I would like to filter out all Sentinel2 tiles where the particular pixel which the point is within is cloudy.

This is different from the more common question of how to filter Sentinel2 tiles based on a threshold percentage of cloudy pixels, for which the Sentinel2 product has a built-in value for each tile (`CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE`).

Here is the code so far, which simply creates a point and uses it to grab available Sentinel2 tiles for that location:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([13.93, -14.51]);

var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterBounds(point) // Filter tile by point
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 20));  // Remove cloudy plots

print(sentinel2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, @Mathieu's answer is heading in the right direction, but I'll expand it with the code: (I made some comments in the code)

```js
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([13.93, -14.51]);

// function to extract the bits info out of QA60 band
var extractQABits = function (qaBand, bitStart, bitEnd) {
  var numBits = bitEnd - bitStart + 1;
  var qaBits = qaBand.rightShift(bitStart).mod(Math.pow(2, numBits));
  return qaBits;
};

// Add a "cloud" binary band to an image (0: no cloud, 1: cloud)
// using QA60 info
var computeClouds = function(img) {
  var qa = img.select('QA60')
  var clouds = extractQABits(qa, 10, 10)
  var cirrus = extractQABits(qa, 11, 11)
  var final = clouds.or(cirrus).rename('clouds')
  return img.addBands(final)
}

// function to write a property in an image indicating
// if the point (argument) is over a cloudy pixel
// the property will be named CLOUDS_AT_POINT and has values
// 0 (no clouds) or 1 (clouds)
var cloudsAtPoint = function(point) {
  var wrap = function(img) {
    var clouds = img.select('clouds')
    var val = clouds.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
      geometry: point,
      scale: 60 // QA60 -> 60m
    }).get('clouds')
    return img.set('CLOUDS_AT_POINT', val)
  }
  return wrap
}

// map all functions over the collection
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterBounds(point) // Filter tile by point
  //.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 20))  // Remove cloudy plots
  .map(computeClouds)
  .map(cloudsAtPoint(point))

// finally, filter the collection with the computed property
var cloudy_collection = sentinel2.filterMetadata('CLOUDS_AT_POINT', 'equals', 1)
var noclouds_collection = sentinel2.filterMetadata('CLOUDS_AT_POINT', 'equals', 0)

// watch results
var vis = {bands:['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], min:0, max:5000}
Map.addLayer(cloudy_collection.first(), vis, 'cloudy')
Map.addLayer(noclouds_collection.first(), vis, 'no clouds')

Map.addLayer(point)
```

Answer (score 1):

keep all of them in the collection and then use the QA60 band to mask cloudy pixel out. It's not perfect but usually a good start.
Whatever reduction you do later, a masked pixel would not affect the result.